# XSLT stylesheet empty paired tags required instead of self-closing tags for null values

Tags: xslt

I have an input which can sometimes have value and sometimes not. Like value1=ABC or value1=""

During my xsl transformation I have my code with the following line

```
<element name="test"><xsl:value-of select="$value1"/><element>
```

The output of the above code when value is present is

```
<element name="test">ABC</element>
```

When the value is not present, the output is

```
<element name="test"/>
```

Now, I want it to look like

```
<element name="test"></element>
```

instead of

```
<element name="test"/>
```

Is it possible to get the required output?
If yes, then how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `<xsl:output method="html"/>`.

Example...

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="test1"/>
        <xsl:variable name="test2" select="'value'"/>
        <element name="test1"><xsl:value-of select="$test1"/></element>
        <element name="test2"><xsl:value-of select="$test2"/></element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces (when applied to any XML instance):

```
<element name="test1"></element>
<element name="test2">value</element>
```

Comment: @SAM - This should only cause a problem in a few cases (for example, if any of your element names are the same as an HTML element or if you're outputting processing instructions). See http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-HTML-Output-Method for more details.

Comment: In this thread (http://p2p.wrox.com/xslt/44616-how-force-xslt-output-close-tag-xml.html) Michael Kay gives an interesting answer: "XSLT outputs a result tree, it doesn't output tags [...] The serializer will decide whether to use <textarea></textarea> or <textarea/>. In XML, both forms are completely equivalent, so any consumer of the XML will accept either [...] The official answer in such cases is to write your own serializer."